# How do I create a noexcept function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, noexcept

I'd like to create a function pointer like this:

```
void(*function_pointer)()noexcept;
```

But, this doesn't work. It seems that an exception specifier in a function declaration is invalid. There must be a way to do this though. *Right?*

*This was linked to a question that is not the same as this. Here I'm asking how to create a function pointer with a noexcept specifier. That was not asked or answered in the question "noexcept specifiers in function typedefs".*

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Compile error? Which compiler? What error?

Comment: http://goo.gl/N9wyLv - seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[except.spec]/2:

> **An *exception-specification* shall appear only on a** function declarator
>   for a function type, **pointer to function type**, reference to function
>   type, or pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of
>   a declaration or definition, or on such a type appearing as a
>   parameter or return type in a function declarator.

So your declaration is indeed well-formed, and Clang [compiles it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/631dc711859b1a4d).

Presumably your compiler is not up to date.